# Why is Volley calling https://safebrowsing.google.com?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

Every once in a while, typically when I do a new install of my App, I will attempt to authenticate with our HTTPS Auth endpoint, the request takes a very long time (around 20-40 seconds) and then fails with an unknown error.  I turned on Verbose Volley tracing and I see this nonsense about safebrowsing.google.com.  What the heck is happening and how do I make it stop?  I am using a Nexus 5 with 4.4 KitKat over wifi.

```
      2662                qtaguid  I  Failed write_ctrl(u 71) res=-1 errno=22
  2662                qtaguid  I  Untagging socket 71 failed errno=-22
  2662   NetworkManagementS..  W  untagSocket(71) failed with errno -22
  2662                 Finsky  D  [1] 3.onErrorResponse: Verification id=7 error response com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "safebrowsing.google.com"
                               : No address associated with hostname
  2662                 Volley  D  [1] Request.finish: 40045 ms: [ ] https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download 0xc9395b26 NORMAL 11
```

Comment: That's a bit disturbing. Have you looked at the Volley source code to see if there is a reference to that URL somewhere?

Comment: Could it be a redirect?

Answer (score 2):

I search inside Volley's code and can't find the URL "safebrowsing.google.com"

I think that maybe your Auth endpoint doesn't accept your request params and redirects you to this domain.

Comment: I've asked around and grepped through all our server code and there is no evidence that the auth endpoint redirects to "safebrowsing.google.com"

Comment: @rooftop, it's strange that the URL included in the error message doesn't exists: `https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download`

Which version of Volley are you using? Did you search this URL in your Volley source code?

Comment: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6

Comment: @rooftop, I can't find this URL in the code of this library version. If this redirection is not present in your Auth server, could this problem be related with your Wifi connection or your DNSs?

Comment: Doubtful. This only happens from time to time, and it seems to only happen after a new build is installed (but not all the time).

Answer (score 0):

It is Google feature to detect potentially harmful app:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2812853?hl=en

Android calc hash of your app and send to Google for check on this address:

https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download

If apk unknown it can upload it to Google for check.